# Can you confuse the query planner by running EXPLAIN too often?

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization

I recently came across [this neat trick](https://www.citusdata.com/blog/2016/10/12/count-performance/) for speeding up counts when I don't need an exact result. The basic idea is that you simply prepend your query (sans `count`) with EXPLAIN to trick the query planner into telling you what it thinks the row count would be. So I started using it in production, mostly on a single large table.

A week later, I ran into a problem with the query planner in production (but not locally with the same data) deciding to do a bunch of nested loop joins when hash joins are perfectly serviceable. In the short term, I'm setting enable_nestloop to false for that query, but could it be that my overuse of EXPLAIN is confusing the planner?

I recently upgraded from version 11 to 14 as well.

Edit: here are the query plans between local (or enable_nestloop = false) and production:

```
                                                                                     QUERY PLAN                                                                                      
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=4420.71..4420.77 rows=25 width=289)
   ->  Sort  (cost=4420.71..4440.50 rows=7917 width=289)
         Sort Key: line_item_t.created DESC
         ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=3372.35..4197.30 rows=7917 width=289)
               Hash Cond: (till_report_t.till = till_t.id)
               ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=3347.72..3835.07 rows=7917 width=584)
                     Hash Cond: (transaction_t.till_report = till_report_t.id)
                     ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=3345.58..3810.42 rows=7917 width=568)
                           Hash Cond: (transaction_t.customer = customer_t.id)
                           ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=3308.40..3752.44 rows=7917 width=533)
                                 Hash Cond: (item_t.supplier = supplier_t.id)
                                 ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=3271.23..3694.32 rows=7917 width=498)
                                       Hash Cond: (item_t.shelf = shelf_t.id)
                                       ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=3249.53..3651.80 rows=7917 width=466)
                                             Hash Cond: (item_t.category = category_t.id)
                                             ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=3242.39..3623.40 rows=7917 width=450)
                                                   Hash Cond: (line_item_t.id = taxes_t.line_item)
                                                   ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=1902.78..2263.00 rows=7917 width=418)
                                                         Hash Cond: (line_item_t.id = discounts_t.line_item)
                                                         ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=1423.73..1763.15 rows=7917 width=386)
                                                               Hash Cond: (line_item_t.id = surcharges_t.line_item)
                                                               ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=866.36..1184.99 rows=7917 width=354)
                                                                     Hash Cond: (line_item_t.item = item_t.id)
                                                                     ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=271.24..569.07 rows=7917 width=192)
                                                                           Hash Cond: (line_item_t.transaction = transaction_t.id)
                                                                           Filter: (transaction_t.status IS DISTINCT FROM 'voided'::text)
                                                                           ->  Seq Scan on line_item line_item_t  (cost=0.00..277.01 rows=7921 width=100)
                                                                                 Filter: (store = '49b2980b-9e62-4c49-b42b-a862d25852a8'::uuid)
                                                                           ->  Hash  (cost=219.44..219.44 rows=4144 width=92)
                                                                                 ->  Seq Scan on transaction transaction_t  (cost=0.00..219.44 rows=4144 width=92)
                                                                     ->  Hash  (cost=521.72..521.72 rows=5872 width=162)
                                                                           ->  Seq Scan on item item_t  (cost=0.00..521.72 rows=5872 width=162)
                                                               ->  Hash  (cost=513.99..513.99 rows=3471 width=48)
                                                                     ->  Subquery Scan on surcharges_t  (cost=392.50..513.99 rows=3471 width=48)
                                                                           ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=392.50..479.28 rows=3471 width=48)
                                                                                 Group Key: applied_surcharge_t.line_item
                                                                                 ->  Sort  (cost=392.50..401.18 rows=3471 width=52)
                                                                                       Sort Key: applied_surcharge_t.line_item
                                                                                       ->  Seq Scan on applied_surcharge applied_surcharge_t  (cost=0.00..188.39 rows=3471 width=52)
                                                                                             Filter: (store = '49b2980b-9e62-4c49-b42b-a862d25852a8'::uuid)
                                                         ->  Hash  (cost=447.41..447.41 rows=2531 width=48)
                                                               ->  Subquery Scan on discounts_t  (cost=357.89..447.41 rows=2531 width=48)
                                                                     ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=357.89..422.10 rows=2531 width=48)
                                                                           Group Key: applied_discount_t.line_item
                                                                           ->  Sort  (cost=357.89..364.45 rows=2625 width=52)
                                                                                 Sort Key: applied_discount_t.line_item
                                                                                 ->  Seq Scan on applied_discount applied_discount_t  (cost=0.00..208.81 rows=2625 width=52)
                                                                                       Filter: (store = '49b2980b-9e62-4c49-b42b-a862d25852a8'::uuid)
                                                   ->  Hash  (cost=1241.22..1241.22 rows=7871 width=48)
                                                         ->  Subquery Scan on taxes_t  (cost=965.73..1241.22 rows=7871 width=48)
                                                               ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=965.73..1162.51 rows=7871 width=48)
                                                                     Group Key: applied_tax_t.line_item
                                                                     ->  Sort  (cost=965.73..985.41 rows=7871 width=52)
                                                                           Sort Key: applied_tax_t.line_item
                                                                           ->  Seq Scan on applied_tax applied_tax_t  (cost=0.00..456.39 rows=7871 width=52)
                                                                                 Filter: (store = '49b2980b-9e62-4c49-b42b-a862d25852a8'::uuid)
                                             ->  Hash  (cost=4.84..4.84 rows=184 width=32)
                                                   ->  Seq Scan on category category_t  (cost=0.00..4.84 rows=184 width=32)
                                       ->  Hash  (cost=15.20..15.20 rows=520 width=48)
                                             ->  Seq Scan on shelf shelf_t  (cost=0.00..15.20 rows=520 width=48)
                                 ->  Hash  (cost=30.41..30.41 rows=541 width=51)
                                       ->  Seq Scan on contact supplier_t  (cost=0.00..30.41 rows=541 width=51)
                           ->  Hash  (cost=30.41..30.41 rows=541 width=51)
                                 ->  Seq Scan on contact customer_t  (cost=0.00..30.41 rows=541 width=51)
                     ->  Hash  (cost=1.51..1.51 rows=51 width=32)
                           ->  Seq Scan on till_report till_report_t  (cost=0.00..1.51 rows=51 width=32)
               ->  Hash  (cost=16.50..16.50 rows=650 width=48)
                     ->  Seq Scan on till till_t  (cost=0.00..16.50 rows=650 width=48)
(68 rows)
```

```
                                                                                       QUERY PLAN                                                                                        
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=2359.85..2359.87 rows=1 width=289)
   ->  Result  (cost=2359.85..2359.87 rows=1 width=289)
         ->  Sort  (cost=2359.85..2359.85 rows=1 width=409)
               Sort Key: line_item_t.created DESC
               ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=2271.47..2359.85 rows=1 width=409)
                     Join Filter: (till_report_t.till = till_t.id)
                     ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=2271.47..2358.43 rows=1 width=480)
                           Join Filter: (transaction_t.till_report = till_report_t.id)
                           ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=2271.47..2357.09 rows=1 width=464)
                                 ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=2271.41..2357.02 rows=1 width=440)
                                       ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=2271.35..2356.95 rows=1 width=416)
                                             Join Filter: (item_t.shelf = shelf_t.id)
                                             ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=2271.35..2355.94 rows=1 width=413)
                                                   Join Filter: (item_t.category = category_t.id)
                                                   ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=2271.35..2347.32 rows=1 width=401)
                                                         Join Filter: (applied_tax_t.line_item = line_item_t.id)
                                                         ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=2267.26..2343.21 rows=1 width=369)
                                                               Join Filter: (applied_discount_t.line_item = line_item_t.id)
                                                               ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=1378.01..1426.46 rows=1 width=337)
                                                                     Join Filter: (applied_surcharge_t.line_item = line_item_t.id)
                                                                     ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.23..12.24 rows=1 width=305)
                                                                           Filter: (transaction_t.status IS DISTINCT FROM 'voided'::text)
                                                                           ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.17..8.18 rows=1 width=213)
                                                                                 ->  Index Scan using line_item_store_index on line_item line_item_t  (cost=0.08..4.09 rows=1 width=100)
                                                                                       Index Cond: (store = '49b2980b-9e62-4c49-b42b-a862d25852a8'::uuid)
                                                                                 ->  Index Scan using item_pk on item item_t  (cost=0.08..4.09 rows=1 width=113)
                                                                                       Index Cond: (id = line_item_t.item)
                                                                           ->  Index Scan using transaction_pk on transaction transaction_t  (cost=0.06..4.06 rows=1 width=92)
                                                                                 Index Cond: (id = line_item_t.transaction)
                                                                     ->  HashAggregate  (cost=1377.79..1391.67 rows=3470 width=48)
                                                                           Group Key: applied_surcharge_t.line_item
                                                                           ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on applied_surcharge applied_surcharge_t  (cost=39.44..1372.58 rows=3470 width=52)
                                                                                 Recheck Cond: (store = '49b2980b-9e62-4c49-b42b-a862d25852a8'::uuid)
                                                                                 ->  Bitmap Index Scan on applied_surcharge_store_index  (cost=0.00..39.26 rows=3470 width=0)
                                                                                       Index Cond: (store = '49b2980b-9e62-4c49-b42b-a862d25852a8'::uuid)
                                                               ->  HashAggregate  (cost=889.25..899.73 rows=2619 width=48)
                                                                     Group Key: applied_discount_t.line_item
                                                                     ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on applied_discount applied_discount_t  (cost=30.13..885.31 rows=2625 width=52)
                                                                           Recheck Cond: (store = '49b2980b-9e62-4c49-b42b-a862d25852a8'::uuid)
                                                                           ->  Bitmap Index Scan on applied_discount_store_index  (cost=0.00..30.00 rows=2625 width=0)
                                                                                 Index Cond: (store = '49b2980b-9e62-4c49-b42b-a862d25852a8'::uuid)
                                                         ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=4.09..4.10 rows=1 width=48)
                                                               Group Key: applied_tax_t.line_item
                                                               ->  Sort  (cost=4.09..4.09 rows=1 width=52)
                                                                     Sort Key: applied_tax_t.line_item
                                                                     ->  Index Scan using applied_tax_store_index on applied_tax applied_tax_t  (cost=0.08..4.09 rows=1 width=52)
                                                                           Index Cond: (store = '49b2980b-9e62-4c49-b42b-a862d25852a8'::uuid)
                                                   ->  Seq Scan on category category_t  (cost=0.00..7.21 rows=404 width=28)
                                             ->  Seq Scan on shelf shelf_t  (cost=0.00..1.00 rows=1 width=19)
                                       ->  Index Scan using contact_pk on contact supplier_t  (cost=0.06..0.07 rows=1 width=40)
                                             Index Cond: (id = item_t.supplier)
                                 ->  Index Scan using contact_pk on contact customer_t  (cost=0.06..0.08 rows=1 width=40)
                                       Index Cond: (id = transaction_t.customer)
                           ->  Seq Scan on till_report till_report_t  (cost=0.00..1.15 rows=51 width=32)
                     ->  Seq Scan on till till_t  (cost=0.00..1.20 rows=65 width=48)
(55 rows)
```

Edit 2: I ran ANALYZE on all the affected tables and my query is running dramatically faster. The query plan still isn't using hash left joins, but it is using indexes/memoize rather than seq scans:

```
                                                                                                                       QUERY PLAN                                                                                                                       
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=11884.38..11950.45 rows=25 width=289) (actual time=103.418..109.963 rows=25 loops=1)
   ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=11884.38..33470.79 rows=8169 width=289) (actual time=103.417..109.958 rows=25 loops=1)
         ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=11884.35..33352.07 rows=8169 width=487) (actual time=103.274..109.286 rows=25 loops=1)
               ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=11884.33..33085.69 rows=8169 width=471) (actual time=103.261..109.239 rows=25 loops=1)
                     ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=11884.27..32921.60 rows=8169 width=447) (actual time=103.250..109.190 rows=25 loops=1)
                           ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=11884.21..32384.36 rows=8169 width=423) (actual time=103.216..108.979 rows=25 loops=1)
                                 Join Filter: (item_t.shelf = shelf_t.id)
                                 Rows Removed by Join Filter: 89
                                 ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=11884.21..32221.21 rows=8169 width=415) (actual time=103.201..108.940 rows=25 loops=1)
                                       ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=11884.15..32147.78 rows=8169 width=403) (actual time=103.180..108.856 rows=25 loops=1)
                                             ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=11884.07..17137.79 rows=8169 width=288) (actual time=103.146..108.516 rows=25 loops=1)
                                                   Filter: (transaction_t.status IS DISTINCT FROM 'voided'::text)
                                                   ->  Gather Merge  (cost=11884.01..12760.26 rows=8205 width=196) (actual time=103.106..108.353 rows=25 loops=1)
                                                         Workers Planned: 1
                                                         Workers Launched: 1
                                                         ->  Sort  (cost=10884.01..10886.42 rows=4826 width=196) (actual time=98.270..98.286 rows=84 loops=2)
                                                               Sort Key: line_item_t.created DESC
                                                               Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 4244kB
                                                               Worker 0:  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 1037kB
                                                               ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=7165.46..10824.95 rows=4826 width=196) (actual time=85.724..93.546 rows=3962 loops=2)
                                                                     Hash Cond: (line_item_t.id = taxes_t.line_item)
                                                                     ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=2423.36..6080.32 rows=4826 width=164) (actual time=36.150..42.054 rows=3962 loops=2)
                                                                           Hash Cond: (line_item_t.id = discounts_t.line_item)
                                                                           ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=1506.60..5161.02 rows=4826 width=132) (actual time=20.669..24.920 rows=3962 loops=2)
                                                                                 Hash Cond: (line_item_t.id = surcharges_t.line_item)
                                                                                 ->  Parallel Bitmap Heap Scan on line_item line_item_t  (cost=92.80..3744.69 rows=4826 width=100) (actual time=0.465..2.835 rows=3962 loops=2)
                                                                                       Recheck Cond: (store = '49b2980b-9e62-4c49-b42b-a862d25852a8'::uuid)
                                                                                       Heap Blocks: exact=154
                                                                                       ->  Bitmap Index Scan on line_item_store_index  (cost=0.00..92.39 rows=8205 width=0) (actual time=0.833..0.833 rows=7923 loops=1)
                                                                                             Index Cond: (store = '49b2980b-9e62-4c49-b42b-a862d25852a8'::uuid)
                                                                                 ->  Hash  (cost=1401.74..1401.74 rows=3445 width=48) (actual time=20.168..20.170 rows=3472 loops=2)
                                                                                       Buckets: 4096  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 756kB
                                                                                       ->  Subquery Scan on surcharges_t  (cost=1377.62..1401.74 rows=3445 width=48) (actual time=15.096..18.776 rows=3472 loops=2)
                                                                                             ->  HashAggregate  (cost=1377.62..1391.40 rows=3445 width=48) (actual time=15.095..18.299 rows=3472 loops=2)
                                                                                                   Group Key: applied_surcharge_t.line_item
                                                                                                   Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 2257kB
                                                                                                   Worker 0:  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 2257kB
                                                                                                   ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on applied_surcharge applied_surcharge_t  (cost=39.40..1372.45 rows=3445 width=52) (actual time=0.355..2.048 rows=3472 loops=2)
                                                                                                         Recheck Cond: (store = '49b2980b-9e62-4c49-b42b-a862d25852a8'::uuid)
                                                                                                         Heap Blocks: exact=175
                                                                                                         ->  Bitmap Index Scan on applied_surcharge_store_index  (cost=0.00..39.23 rows=3445 width=0) (actual time=0.314..0.314 rows=3473 loops=2)
                                                                                                               Index Cond: (store = '49b2980b-9e62-4c49-b42b-a862d25852a8'::uuid)
                                                                           ->  Hash  (cost=907.60..907.60 rows=2620 width=48) (actual time=15.453..15.455 rows=2532 loops=2)
                                                                                 Buckets: 4096  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 575kB
                                                                                 ->  Subquery Scan on discounts_t  (cost=889.26..907.60 rows=2620 width=48) (actual time=11.729..14.389 rows=2532 loops=2)
                                                                                       ->  HashAggregate  (cost=889.26..899.74 rows=2620 width=48) (actual time=11.728..14.067 rows=2532 loops=2)
                                                                                             Group Key: applied_discount_t.line_item
                                                                                             Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 2161kB
                                                                                             Worker 0:  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 2161kB
                                                                                             ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on applied_discount applied_discount_t  (cost=30.13..885.32 rows=2626 width=52) (actual time=0.262..1.828 rows=2626 loops=2)
                                                                                                   Recheck Cond: (store = '49b2980b-9e62-4c49-b42b-a862d25852a8'::uuid)
                                                                                                   Heap Blocks: exact=176
                                                                                                   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on applied_discount_store_index  (cost=0.00..30.00 rows=2626 width=0) (actual time=0.226..0.227 rows=2627 loops=2)
                                                                                                         Index Cond: (store = '49b2980b-9e62-4c49-b42b-a862d25852a8'::uuid)
                                                                     ->  Hash  (cost=4714.02..4714.02 rows=8023 width=48) (actual time=49.510..49.512 rows=7873 loops=2)
                                                                           Buckets: 8192  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 1660kB
                                                                           ->  Subquery Scan on taxes_t  (cost=4657.85..4714.02 rows=8023 width=48) (actual time=37.618..46.171 rows=7873 loops=2)
                                                                                 ->  HashAggregate  (cost=4657.85..4689.95 rows=8023 width=48) (actual time=37.617..45.174 rows=7873 loops=2)
                                                                                       Group Key: applied_tax_t.line_item
                                                                                       Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 8593kB
                                                                                       Worker 0:  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 8593kB
                                                                                       ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on applied_tax applied_tax_t  (cost=90.52..4645.82 rows=8023 width=52) (actual time=0.915..4.077 rows=7873 loops=2)
                                                                                             Recheck Cond: (store = '49b2980b-9e62-4c49-b42b-a862d25852a8'::uuid)
                                                                                             Heap Blocks: exact=361
                                                                                             ->  Bitmap Index Scan on applied_tax_store_index  (cost=0.00..90.12 rows=8023 width=0) (actual time=0.857..0.857 rows=7873 loops=2)
                                                                                                   Index Cond: (store = '49b2980b-9e62-4c49-b42b-a862d25852a8'::uuid)
                                                   ->  Index Scan using transaction_pk on transaction transaction_t  (cost=0.06..0.53 rows=1 width=92) (actual time=0.006..0.006 rows=1 loops=25)
                                                         Index Cond: (id = line_item_t.transaction)
                                             ->  Index Scan using item_pk on item item_t  (cost=0.08..1.84 rows=1 width=115) (actual time=0.013..0.013 rows=1 loops=25)
                                                   Index Cond: (id = line_item_t.item)
                                       ->  Memoize  (cost=0.06..0.06 rows=1 width=28) (actual time=0.003..0.003 rows=1 loops=25)
                                             Cache Key: item_t.category
                                             Cache Mode: logical
                                             Hits: 9  Misses: 16  Evictions: 0  Overflows: 0  Memory Usage: 3kB
                                             ->  Index Scan using category_pk on category category_t  (cost=0.05..0.06 rows=1 width=28) (actual time=0.003..0.003 rows=1 loops=16)
                                                   Index Cond: (id = item_t.category)
                                 ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..1.02 rows=5 width=24) (actual time=0.000..0.001 rows=4 loops=25)
                                       ->  Seq Scan on shelf shelf_t  (cost=0.00..1.01 rows=5 width=24) (actual time=0.009..0.011 rows=5 loops=1)
                           ->  Index Scan using contact_pk on contact supplier_t  (cost=0.06..0.07 rows=1 width=40) (actual time=0.008..0.008 rows=1 loops=25)
                                 Index Cond: (id = item_t.supplier)
                     ->  Memoize  (cost=0.06..0.08 rows=1 width=40) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=0 loops=25)
                           Cache Key: transaction_t.customer
                           Cache Mode: logical
                           Hits: 22  Misses: 3  Evictions: 0  Overflows: 0  Memory Usage: 1kB
                           ->  Index Scan using contact_pk on contact customer_t  (cost=0.06..0.08 rows=1 width=40) (actual time=0.008..0.008 rows=1 loops=3)
                                 Index Cond: (id = transaction_t.customer)
               ->  Index Scan using till_report_pkey on till_report till_report_t  (cost=0.03..0.03 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=1 loops=25)
                     Index Cond: (id = transaction_t.till_report)
         ->  Memoize  (cost=0.03..0.15 rows=1 width=25) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=1 loops=25)
               Cache Key: till_report_t.till
               Cache Mode: logical
               Hits: 24  Misses: 1  Evictions: 0  Overflows: 0  Memory Usage: 1kB
               ->  Index Scan using till_pk on till till_t  (cost=0.03..0.15 rows=1 width=25) (actual time=0.022..0.022 rows=1 loops=1)
                     Index Cond: (id = till_report_t.till)
 Planning Time: 11.515 ms
 Execution Time: 111.673 ms
(96 rows)
```

Comment: No.  It is just a coincidence.  Seek the root cause directly, not by 'post hoc ergo propter hoc'.  What are the plans of the problem queries with and without `enable_nestloop to false`?

Comment: With nestloop on, production gives me lots of nested loop joins, and my local installation (same data, same database version) gives me all hash joins. If I turn enable_nestloop off, production gives me hash joins as well.

Comment: Explain shows you the query plan, the plan the database has to calculate anyway

Comment: Yes, I'm using explain analyze, just updated my question.

Comment: Could it be the production has less `work_mem` to work with and hence skips on using hash joins? (compare other values from `pg_setttings` too, there might be more differences between your local and your prod environment that influence the query planner)

Comment: Production actually has more work_mem: 102400 vs local's 4096. Other than that, cpu_x_cost settings are lower in production, effective_cache_size and shared_buffers are much higher on production, max_locks_per_transaction is 64 in production vs 256 on local, random_page_cost is 2 in production, 4 on local.